# Select DropDown not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a problem in a responsive view. When I click select options it does not work on mobile view.

This is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <label class="MB10">Select</label>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option>Choose Option</option>
            <option>Option One</option>
            <option>Option two</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I attached code and images.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple class in `select` tag like below

```
 <select class="form-control" multiple>
     <option>Choose Option</option>
     <option>Option One</option>
     <option>Option two</option>
 </select>
```

to select multiple options pres `CTRL` and click on multiple options (for desktop)
,In mobile view you will get checkboxes to select multiple options

Answer (score 0):

Might be other div overlapping on select dropdown,So your select not working on mobile. Try to find out it using firebug.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form>
 <div class="ui-field-contain">
  <label for="select-native-1">Basic:</label>
   <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
     <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
     <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
     <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
     <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</form>
```

here is the  [link for working example](https://jsfiddle.net/cdpt93w1/)